# Missing identifier even though it's defined one line above?

Tags: java, unicode, syntax

Let's see this trivial Java program:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int а = 2;
        System.out.println("a " + a);
    }
}
```

It creates the variable `a` initialized to `2`, and prints it. However, it doesn't compile:

```
    $ javac A.java && java A
    A.java:4: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : variable a
    location: class A
            System.out.println("a " + a);
                                      ^
    1 error
```

Why?

Comment: Looks like your file to compile hasn't been saved correctly and is missing the `a` variable declaration. It would be better to restart your IDE or try to compile it manually.

Comment: It seems the code was copy-pasted from site which preserved the char encoding !!!

Comment: @downvoters, this is a valid question. You need to copy and paste it into your **unicode compatible editor** from your **unicode compatible browser** to make it work. See the answer for explanation.

Comment: Why is this is closed for being too localized? The only way I can see that this is "localized" is that some browsers don't support unicode. Should I post the hex of the code for people who are using old browsers? Or is there somewhere I can upload the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got two different types of `a` there. If you retype the first one as ASCII `a`, it's fine.

The first `a` is U+0430, "Cyrrilic small letter a". (See the [relevant Unicode chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf).)

I would personally try to keep all identifiers in Java as ASCII characters where possible.

(Where did this code even come from to start with?)

Comment: This guy is messing with us.

Comment: @Dog: But where did the source file *start* from? This isn't the kind of thing which usually happens without someone trying to play a joke...

Comment: It was edited by several people, we have people of many ethnic backgrounds here. I guess you could say people's locales/text editors/OS are playing a joke.

Comment: @Dog: But it would have caused a problem immediately for whoever first typed in the declaration... Oh well - at least it's sorted now.

Comment: Oh I see, there were 2 `a`'s in the same scope, the weird one was a static class variable, the normal one was a local variable, the problem was when I tried to access the static variable outside that method that had the normal `a` in it..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is that, but on the `int а = 2;` line, that thing most certainly is not an `a`, a.k.a ASCII 97.